# Explaining: The probability of breaking an encryption scheme

Tags: probability

I was reading intro to modern cryptography and didn't understand how did they calculate the probability:

> Say we have a cryptographic scheme in which an honest parties run for $10^6 \cdot n^2$ cycles and for which an adversary running for $10^8 \cdot n^4$ cycles can succeed in breaking the scheme with probability at least $2^{-n/2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They didn't. They made up some numbers as an example, likely to be used in the following text.